# When tagging users, add an option to choose the user to ping

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies, gravatar

[image]

Kind of hard to identify a user if there are two completely separate users with different names.  According to this user [Gilles](https://stackexchange.com/users/164368/gilles) (moderator on French Language, CompSci and this user [Gilles](https://stackexchange.com/users/1823107/mew) (on Puzzling.SE), the only way to really differentiate from the two is to see the gravatars that hey have picked.

And since you can't tell which Gilles is the one you actually want to ping, how we would we go about this? The latter Gilles apparently [insists that having identical names as someone is okay](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/lateral-thinking-is-a-poor-excuse-for-a-bad-answer#comment3361_1537).

So here's my request.  Add the gravatar to the names that pop up when you are attempting to tag someone, so that you get the right user.  I understand this may be fairly niche, that two users with the same username could be active in the same question, but this can cause issues when trying to ping someone I didn't actually want to ping.

As psubsee2003 points out, the first thing to actually address is choosing a user to ping, THEN adding gravatars to identify the user.

Comment: First step already requested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125994/how-to-reply-to-one-user-among-two-having-same-names.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Since 2012 ;_;

Comment: Yup, feature requests can sit for long years, there's no guarantee they will be done or get official response.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132562/165773

Answer (score 7):

Before adding a gravatar, you need to request a feature that actually will allow you to select the specific user you want to ping.

The way the system is designed at the moment, you can't select a specific user, so it won't matter which name you pick from the pop-up.  Clicking in the dropdown will only ping the `Gilles` that commented last regardless of the name you select.

Comment: Good point, I didn't really catch that. So I'll re-edit my question, thanks!

Comment: The "only the one that commented last" part is correct, but the "any user with matching 3 characters" is wrong. When you type `@Gilles`, you don't notify anyone called "Gilbert". That wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @balpha edited that part out then.  I think I either misunderstood or misremembered the details in what I read before.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: It should be considered a bug that when you click on a user's name from the popup, the notification may still go to the other user.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposal wouldn't remove *reading* confusion, which would be good to resolve at the same time.

Also, you'd have to view the profile of the comment you're replying to, to know which gravatar to use.

I think this already resolves your issue, including my two points above:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126047/230506

When same usernames are present in a question, the system can just serve up their unique ID next to their username.
It would need to show it on both the comments, and the ping options, so you can marry them up.

So comments when there's two users with username "James", would look like:

- hmm, yeah, blah, rhubarb! - James (334455) 35 mins ago
- ok, thanks, will do! - James (667788) 15 mins ago

Then when typing `@Jam` you'd get the options:
`James (334455) - James (667788)`

So the unique identifier (userid) shows which comments belong to the different James', and that gives you a unique identifier to easily choose which one to reply to (for the ping to work).

I don't see this being much of a real problem though, with such a likely low frequency.
How often do you see this occur?

Comment: And who's going to know what the ID refers to without looking at their profile page?

Comment: @euphoriaoverlord It doesn't matter. The question is not about trying to identify a particular user among same usernames. It's about identifying a specific user's comment, so when you reply your ping goes to the user you are replying to, not one of the other users with the same username.

Comment: I hate it when people say "it's not a big deal since it doesn't happen often".  Good programming should handle all edge cases.  Not only that, but since SE is supposedly about quality content, then you would want to make sure the correct person is notified in case you want them to improve their Q or A.

Comment: @pacoverflow I agree - if you're going to do something do it right. However, there's a difference between a bug, an issue, and this which is "by design", in that there is no "fault" just something extra could be introduced to add improvement. And the lacking of this functionality doesn't affect the quality or usability of the site, especially given the *severity* of the outcome and the *frequency* of occurrence. The reason I brought up frequency is because Stack usually doesn't make changes unless it's a bug or problem, is useful to many, or is *incredibly* useful to a few.

Comment: @James Like I mentioned in a comment to the other answer, I do think this should be considered a bug. When you click on one of the usernames in the popup, you are telling the system to send a notification to that user, but the notification might still go to the other user.

Comment: @pacoverflow Surely a bug is when something doesn't work as intended? "*the notification might still go to the other user*" You make it sound like it's random, or there's no structured process or system. The ping goes to the user based on what the system is scripted to do, and will every time. When commenting to one of two (or more) users with the same username, your comment will ping the user with the most recent comment. It is designed that way, and works fine, so not really a "bug". It could be improved, however.

Comment: True, that's how the system is designed, but for users who don't realize that, it definitely seems like a bug.  There was another meta discussion a few weeks ago describing how a user directed a comment to a user named "tim" by typing @tim, but the notification was actually sent to the user "timrau".  The way this comment notification system is designed is definitely unintuitive.