# How can I reply comments posted by 2 users with identical name?

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

How can I reply to a specific user If 2 users with indentical names post comments on my question?

ex :
Look at the following comments posted by 2 diffrent users :

```
What have you tried so far - Mark B

Have you checked your error log? - mark B
```

In this situation How can I reply to the first comment with @username?

Comment: Wait what? This actually happened? Wowz.

Comment: In short: you can't.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125994/how-to-reply-to-one-user-among-two-having-same-names | http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work > *"Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if five people named John are participating, @john will match the most recent John."*