# Comment ping one of two users with same name?

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies

I would like to address the first "Michael" in this [comment thread](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/84320/someone-elses-lock-on-my-bike)

[image]

---

I found this at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/235923:

> Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if five people named John are participating, @john will match the most recent John. (Use the next rule to differentiate.)

but I don't see how I can use it to target the first "Michael".

I even checked the source code of those hints and they seem to be based on display name, not user ID.

---

Can we have a way to explicitly ping one of the two users with the same name?

Comment: This is not possible. Should start a feature request asking to make it possible, but pretty sure there is one already.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar I did start a Feature request. Apparently some editor thought they understood my question better than I do...

Comment: Indeed, @Justin edit was wrong, didn't notice sorry. Would have rolled it back, as we should **not** make such changes. Feature request is a feature request, not support question.

Comment: A feature request needs to include a suggestion on how *you* would like it to be. Currently, this looks like a support question to me.

Comment: @Justin OK, look what I did [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125994/how-to-reply-to-one-user-among-two-having-same-names). Same can be done in this question as well if you want.

Comment: @Justin Dude, "and avoid focusing on your ideas about the solution" right from https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar Yeah, unfortunately a 10-year old post doesn't have much influence; it's clearly been ignored. It's sometimes necessary to resurrect old topic with fresh eyes.

Comment: "How do I guarantee that the first Michael in the comment thread gets pinged?" is clearly a support question. "Can we have a way to ping one of the two users with the same name?" is a feature request.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus most feature requests are "ignored", with thousands of them, it's impossible for SE team to respond to them all, that's something I can understand. So we do what we can, bump old requests sometimes, and hope for the best. Still, the duplicate system working fine, this new question is a new signpost pointing to the original, and the original was bumped to homepage as well now, by the title edit I just made. Same way, I can start bounty when there's nothing to improve in the post itself.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar Marking my post as a dupe so quickly effectively makes everything "dead in the water", yet again...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus no, it's not. Leaving the same requests open won't have any better effect.